# How to create user flow diagrams with BPMN?

Tags: bpmn, wireframe, mockups

Wireframes are a kind of blueprints when designing frontends. I recently came across an extension to that called *"user flows"* or *"UI flows"*, which visualizes parts of the interactivity of the user interface (UI) as a flow chart. They look nice but are often not easy to user further for programming purposes (like generating code). If you are lucky, you can export an XML-representation of a user flow, but often they just look pretty and are only accessible as (non-vector) graphics. That is why it would be cool to somehow marry that with BPMN.

I ask you for some input (in terms of search keywords, links or comments):
**I am looking for a guide or best practises on how to draw user flows with BPMN.** Ideally some short introduction like [Camunda's BPMN introduction](https://camunda.com/bpmn/).

[image: User flow:]

**References:**

- Wikipedia on [Wireframes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire-frame_model)
- Alexander Handley: [User flow is the new wireframe](https://uxdesign.cc/when-to-use-user-flows-guide-8b26ca9aa36a)
- [UI flow software example](https://www.mockplus.com/) from whose advertisement-video I got the attached screenshot
- One of its competitors: https://overflow.io/ without the stack :-)
- [More UI-flow tools](https://alternativeto.net/software/mockplus/)

Comment: Maybe this question can be better fielded by UX Stack Exchange community ?

Comment: @khalito I thought of that, but there BPMN is not too well known. I am more interested in the developer / BPMN expert perspective.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "they look nice but are not easy to use further". How do you intend on using your flow chart or process diagram further in your context ? Do you mean along the lines of what Alexander Handley described as his steps 3-4 (for example, automatically generate wireframes / user flow examples based on your diagram) ? I have a feeling the "way you use them further" has not much to do with the notation you have used to design your process but purely with the (software) tools.

Comment: @khalito: I edited my post so that it becomes less prone to misunderstanding. You might be right that it my question could be a problem of the software which I use for wireframing, but I am also interested in the theoretical point of view: **Is there a mapping between BPMN and any kind of wireframing notation standard?**